# How does pipe() identify file descriptor

Tags: linux, pipe

I am recently learning linux OS. And I have a question about the pipe() function.
If I define an `int fd[2]`, does the pipe() automatically know that `fd[0]`is read and `fd[1]` is write?

And if I would like to create a bijection pipe, does that mean I should define two array `int fd[2]` and `int fd_1[2]`?  Do I have to use 'fd' as the array name? Can I use others??

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by definition of the [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) syscall. On success, it fills the two elements of the array you are passing it (the first of index `[0]` being the read end, the second of index `[1]` being the write end). Don't forget to test against the error case.

The name of the argument you are passing to `pipe` -or to any C function- is irrelevant (in particular, because such names are only known at compile time, not at runtime; also it could be some complex pointer expression). But at runtime it should be a pointer to a valid memory zone of two `int`-s

Please read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), and take the habit of reading the documentation of every function that you are using.

Read also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [socketpair(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

You often call  [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) before [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and you generally [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) different ends of the pipe in the father and the child process.

Comment: Thanks!! Can I create two pipes and close close read and write end in correct process part? Will that be working? Thanks!!

Comment: You can create as many pairs of pipes as the kernel permit (typically you could call `pipe` several thousands times).

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the read end in a process and close the write end in the other to make a succesfull data transfer.
You can name the array whatever you like.
From what I remember, only the BSDs support some kind of bidirectional pipes.

Comment: No, you don't have to close the pipes. But you usually should.